# dynamic multiple select for category/subcategory/keywords

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors, jquery-chosen

I am battling with this for few weeks now and can't get it work.
In my database I have Single Table Inherited for Category Subcategory and Keywords. They are in tree structure through parent_id.

The chosen script seem to work for each individual list. But I can't figure out how dynamically handle relationship between Parent and Children, so in Subcategories list would be available options that only belongs to my pre selected Category(one or few).

Here what I have in my script.

```
jQuery(function($){
$(".chosen-input").chosen().trigger("liszt:updated");
$(".schosen-input").chosen().change(function(){
  var subcategories = $("companies_categories").children('select:visible').val();
  });
$(".kchosen-input").chosen().change(function(){
  var keywords = $("companies_subcategories").children('select:visible').val();
  });
});
```

My Form Looks fine.

[image: This is my forms]

Chosen script works.

[image]

**Filtering shows me whole list of Subcategories. But I need only children of perviously preselected Category.**

[image]

Same with Keywords.

[image]

HTML

```
 <fieldset class="inputs"><legend><span>Categories</span></legend><ol>
 <li class="select input optional" id="company_categories_input">
<input name="company[category_ids][]" type="hidden" value="" />
<label class=" label" for="company_category_ids">Categories</label>
<input name="company[category_ids][]" type="hidden" value="" />
<select class="chosen-input" id="company_category_ids" multiple="multiple" 
name="company[category_ids][]"  style="width: 700px;">


<option value="50">Apparel &amp; Luggage</option>
<option value="126">Automotive, RV, Cycling &amp; Other Transportation</option>
<option value="180">Baby, Toddler &amp; Children</option>
<option value="208">Beauty &amp; Personal Care</option>
<option value="288">Chemicals</option>
<option value="331">Arts, Crafts, Hobbies &amp; Fabrics</option>
<option value="392">Electronics &amp; Computers</option>
30 More records
 <option value="461">Fitness &amp; Sports</option></select></li>

<li class="select input optional" id="company_subcategories_input">
<input name="company[subcategory_ids][]" type="hidden" value="" />
<label class=" label" for="company_subcategory_ids">Subcategories</label>
<input name="company[subcategory_ids][]" type="hidden" value="" />
<select class="schosen-input" id="company_subcategory_ids" multiple="multiple"
name="company[subcategory_ids][]" style="width: 700px;">

<option value="13">Small Kitchen Appliances</option>
<option value="24">Laundry &amp; Garment Care</option>
<option value="28">Home Appliances</option>
<option value="36">Commercial Grade Appliances</option>
<option value="46">Appliance Cleaners</option>
Few more hundreds records
<option value="1811">Management of Bank Holding Companies &amp; 
Corporate Offices</option></select></li>

<li class="select input optional" id="company_keywords_input">
<input name="company[keyword_ids][]" type="hidden" value="" />
<label class=" label" for="company_keyword_ids">Keywords</label>
<input name="company[keyword_ids][]" type="hidden" value="" />
<select class="schosen-input" id="company_keyword_ids" multiple="multiple"
name="company[keyword_ids][]" style="width: 700px;">

<option value="5">Ranges - Range Hoods</option>
<option value="6">Ovens - Warming Drawers</option>
<option value="7">Stoves - Cooktops</option>
<option value="8">Dishwashers</option>
<option value="9">Disposers - Trash Compactors</option>
Over 1000 more records
<option value="1179">Soil Amendment - Soil Preperation - Composting - 
Garden Care - Nursery Products</option></select>
</li></ol></fieldset>
```

Seems like I am missing alot. But don't know where to begin with this.

Comment: How does your HTML structure look like ??

Comment: Hi Sushanth, thanks for reply. I added html outcome.

Comment: I do also have /categories.json

Comment: May be this question can help you?

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13789103/javascript-issue-with-jquery-chosen-and-my-calling-code?rq=1